# Printing boost::graph edge_descriptor

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I am using a `boost::graph` and I noticed that when I am just using `std::cout << *ei` where `ei` is an edges iterator obtained, for example, from `boost::edges` command, I see that something like **"(x, y)"** is printed, where **x** and **y** are integers. I assume that these numbers represent vertices descriptors. 
According to this, I have some questions:

- does the default type for `vertex_descriptor` representation in `boost::graph` is int?
- Is there any `operator<<` for `edge_descriptor` is defined inside boost to make the output look like I described above? Otherwise, I cannot understand how it works in this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **Q.** does the default type for vertex_descriptor representation in boost::graph is int?

`boost::graph` is not a type.

Many graph types exist (BGL is a generic template library).

The actual type of vertex_descriptor is opaque, and can be integral. E.g. it is integral¹ with `vecS` vertex container selection in the `adjacecy_list` template argument list.

> **Q.** Is there any operator<< for edge_descriptor is defined inside boost to make the output look like I described above? Otherwise, I cannot understand how it works in this way.

**Yes**. For such a graph type, the following overload of `operator<<` is injected into namespace `std` (see `boost/graph/detail/edge.hpp`):

```
namespace std {

  template <class Char, class Traits, class D, class V>
  std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& 
  operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& os,
             const boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<D,V>& e)
  {
    return os << "(" << e.m_source << "," << e.m_target << ")";
  }

}
```

---

¹ Note that it's likely `size_t`, not `int`